# How to more efficiently localize huge project in Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, automation, laravel-5.4

I have to localize a huge laravel project.

I'm using the short keys feature but that means I have to go through all the views and copy paste strings into a language resource folder. This is a very time consuming process.

Is there a way to automatically extract all the strings from a blade file and generate a language resource file?

Comment: do you have modular app structure?

Comment: What about your [own research first](https://quickadminpanel.com/blog/10-best-laravel-packages-for-multi-language-projects/)? :)

Comment: @adam Yes I have a modular app structure.

Comment: @kyslik Those tools help me manage already translated strings. I need a tool that will extract raw text from the blade files and add them to a resource file for me so that I can send them to translator.